# pandas, creating dataframes based on tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a tuple that has data for several categories. Now I want to extract small dataframes from this tuple for each category based on a list I created. I want to give to each dataframe the name that I have in the list.

The big tuple I have is named 'out' and it contains data for all animals. The list of categories that I want to extract is like below

```
  cat_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'snake']
```

I want to create separate dataframes for each category. I get each df like this

```
  cat = out['cat']
  dog = out['dog']
  snake = out['snake']
```

But I want to do this in a for loop for the list I pass in. I tried something like this

```
  for i in cat_list:
      i = out[i]
```

But I get error:

```
  SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: If `out` is a tuple, you can't use `out['cat']`. Tuples have numeric indexes, string indexes are for dictionaries.

Comment: I don't see any way that the code you posted can cause that error.

Comment: ok, perhaps it is a dictionary. Is there a way to do this from a dictionary?

Comment: What you've written should work.

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/lNTtaV

Comment: it doesnt work for me. Gives error: NameError: name 'cat' is not defined when I try to look at cat df

Comment: it seems to be giving df only for the last item in list

Comment: You shouldn't be creating separate variables since the names are dynamic. Either put everything in a single df where the animal name is a column, or use a dictionary where the animal name is the key and the value is the df.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to create is a panda series. Code [link](https://ideone.com/QnRSO7)

```
import pandas as pd
 
out = {
    "cat": 1,
    "dog": 2,
    "snake": 3
}
cat_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'snake']
 
panda_series = {}
for i in cat_list:
    panda_series[i] = pd.Series(out[i], name=i)
 
for key, series in panda_series.items():
    print(series)
```